GSheets: use regextract if value contains : else, use cell value
I have the code below which checks a cell to see if it has numbers and/or special characters and excludes the numbers and special characters.
How can i change this to do this to do both the previous version and if no numbers or special characters are present, just return the cell value?
e.g. This value:

2021-38: How to Be a Better CFO (SIM)

currently returns:

How to Be a Better CFO SIM

But if it just shows:

How to Be a Better CFO (SIM)

I want the value to return as such

How to Be a Better CFO SIM

=ArrayFormula(if(row(E:E)=1,"Course Name Identifier",IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(E:E,":([^\(]+)") &" SIM"))))


To confirm, you also want to remove all texts inside the parenthesis (like in (SIM))?

If it has parenthesis, I still want to remove the parenthesis and keep the text inside.

So the last one should be How to Be a Better CFO SIM, correct?

I added the SIM back in to ensure accuracy. But yes.

I think I figured it out. =ArrayFormula(if(row(E:E)=1,"Course Name Identifier",IFERROR(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(E:E,":([^(]+)") &" SIM"),E:E)))

Actually, you only need REGEXREPLACE for this. Simply replace all non letters with a blank ("").

it will not affect cells with letters on it

This question is similar to: Use REGEXEXTRACT() to extract only upper case letters from a sentence in Google sheets.


You may try:
=arrayformula(trim(regexreplace(A:A,"[^a-zA-Z ]",)))


